# Report fails to print and export to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, crystal-reports

I'm working with an asp.net web form Crystal report. The report generates when I pass the parameter but it fails to print and export to PDF. Nothing happens when I click the export button, and there is no error message.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString);
    ReportDocument test = new ReportDocument();
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT_DATA", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@INPUT", TextBox1.Text));
    da.Fill(ds);
    test.Load(Server.MapPath("EOR.rpt"));
    test.SetDataSource(ds);
    test.SetParameterValue("input", TextBox1.Text);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = test;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    cn.Close();
}
```

I copied the file to my website project:

> Copy
>
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319  folder and
>   paste to my project folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the browser javascript console to see if there's a problem linked to `CrystalReportViewer` missing a js reference (`*bobj is undefined*`).

In that case, try to add to your printing page the script reference to the `crv.js` file (In the folder you paste in your project. Mine was located at `4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js`)

Comment: checked my project folder , the crv.js file is exist

Comment: Try to add a script reference to that file in your page, before the CrystalViewer control